# Swift get CGPoint of last character in UILabel

Tags: swift, swift3, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView in my project including UIlabel scrolling horizontally, this label is increasable text horizontally.

After search I found this code, but the issue it's always find x position of first match character

Here is my code

```
        if let range = mylabel.text?.range(of: String(describing: mylabel.text?.characters.last!)) {
        let prefix = mylabel.text?.substring(to: range.lowerBound)
        let size: CGSize = prefix!.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 35.0)])
        let position = CGPoint(x:size.width,y: 0)
        myScrollView.setContentOffset(position, animated: true)

    }
```

I need to find x position of last character in label string for scrolling automatically to there
Thx

Comment: Why are you using _loweBound_ here -> `let prefix = mylabel.text?.substring(to: range.lowerBound)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the width of the text with:

```
label.intrinsicContentSize.width
```

Then just add that to the label's X position, assuming the text is left-aligned.

Comment: This what I'm looking for , Thx